# Github. The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file

Tags: github, configuration, github-pages

I have a problem on my files.
Github say "Your site is published at https://evil-dave-dev.github.io/testHTML/"
But when i try it, it display a 404 error and "The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file".
My pages site is currently being built from the main branch.[config github page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDKnt.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The home page shows a file called '`index.html`', which is not present in your GitHub repository. At  first create a HTML file named `index.html` and it will work as your home page.
 But you have a file named '`test.html`' that is reachable on
[`https://evil-dave-dev.github.io/testHTML/test.html`](https://evil-dave-dev.github.io/testHTML/test.html) or [`https://evil-dave-dev.github.io/testHTML/test`](https://evil-dave-dev.github.io/testHTML/test)

Comment: Ooooh ok, i didn't understand that. Thank you for your advice.
Now, I have an other question. Does the HTML file have to be named `index.html` ?

Comment: Yes, there has to be a HTML file in your repository named 'index.html', which will work as your homepage that is [https://evil-dave-dev.github.io](https://evil-dave-dev.github.io/testHTML/test.html). Or you can simply rename your 'test.html' file to 'index.html'.